# How to test ngrx pipe select in Rxjs 6

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, ngrx

Previously I could test the below store select

```
this.store.select(fromRoot.someselector).pipe(map(r => this.store.dispatch(new Action())));
```

This was in my test

```
{provide: Store, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['select']);

store.select.and.returnValue(of({}));
```

But now it has changed to pipes

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.someselector));

this.store.pipe(
        select(fromRoot.someselector), 
        filter(result => !!result), 
        map(r => { 
             if (result === ' hello') { 
               this.store.dispatch(new Action()); 
             } 
           }
        ));
```

How to test this especially when you have map after select and within it you are dispatching an action and you want verify action was called.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the operators and test directly the result of the stream:

```
store
  .pipe(select('selector'))
  .subscribe(val => expect(val).toBe(theMockedValSentToTheSpy))
```

To explain further:

- create a mock of your store
- create a mock of your value
- return this mocked value in your mocked store
- expect your component variable to return the mocked value

This gives:

```
const mockedValue = { id: 1 };
const storeSubjectMock = new BehaviorSubject(mockedValue);
const mockedStore = {
  pipe: () => storeSubjectMock.asObservable(),
};

// { provide: Store, useValue: mockedStore }; in your testbed

it('should return an unaltered value', () => {
  component.variableReferencingStore
    .pipe(select('selector'))
    .subscribe(val => expect(val).toBe(mockedValue))
});
```

Now the good thing about that is that you can test all operators like that. Say your component variable is

```
storeValue$ = this.store.pipe(
  select('selector'),
  map(value => ({ ...value, name: 'customName' }))
)
```

Then your tests just changes to:

```
it('should return an altered value with a name property set to customName', () => {
  component.variableReferencingStore
    .pipe(select('selector'))
    .subscribe(val => expect(val).toEqual({ ...mockedValue, name: 'customName'))
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have to provide store in my test and spy on pipe so question is what would i returnValue of pipe ...store.pipe.and.returnValue(of({})); Also, there is some logic going on in my pipe as shown in the example e.g. map() ..I want to test that also

Comment: No sure if I fully understand it. How would this be test this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.someselector), filter(result => !!result), map(r => if (result === ' hello') { this.store.dispatch(new Action()); }  ));

Comment: I have edited the store statement with a bit complex one to get an idea how that would be tested. Can you please tell me how to go about this one?

Comment: If you don't know how to test your code, I suggest you make another question. I'm not answering you on that through comments ...

Comment: @trichetriche do you know how to get the `selector` passed in to `pipe` to select the desired property instead of the entire mocked object?

Comment: @obl same principle, just test that the end result is the result of the selector

Answer (score 0):

spyOn(store, 'pipe').and.callFake(selector => { return of(true); });
...
expect(store.pipe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // pass